# Javascript Solr (facet) query script not working correctly

Tags: javascript, solr, solrclient

I'm using [solr-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/solr-client) to perform a faceted Solr query, and the result of my javascript solr query script doesn't match what's listed in Solr.

So in Solr, the query I've created is as below. This gives the results I'm after.

[image]

And my corresponding javascript facet query script is as below.

```
exports.list_of_all_car_trims = function(solrPrdCfsClient, callback) {
var carTrimsQuery = solrPrdCfsClient.createQuery()
.q('*:*')
.start(0)
.rows(10)
.matchFilter('ManufacturerName','Ford')
.matchFilter('RangeModelWithYears','Fusion (02-12)')
.facet({
    field:'TrimName',
    mincount:'1'
});
solrPrdCfsClient.search(carTrimsQuery,function(err,obj) {
    if(err) {
        callback(err,null);
    }
    else {
        callback(null, obj.facet_counts.facet_fields);
        console.log(obj.facet_counts.facet_fields);
    }
});
};
```

However, the result of my javascript query script doesn't match the results from Solr.

I'm presuming I've got the correct filters (**'ManufacturerName','Ford'** & **'RangeModelWithYears','Fusion (02-12)')**, but maybe not in the correct positions within the javascript query script?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The position of the fllters should not influence the results. Can you develop how they are different from one query to the other ?

Comment: .. and if you want to replicate the query - why not just use the `q` part of your query in the Javascript client as well, instead of reformulating it?

Comment: I've tried the following code `.q({ManufacturerName:'Ford', RangeModelWithYears: 'Fusion (02-12)'})` but this returned an empty result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought this might be something 'minor' that I was missing, and it was (although this 'minor' thing was failing my whole test!).

Because my **matchFilter** criteria included spaces, I needed to add some speech marks around this.

My code below works.

```
exports.list_of_all_car_trims = function(solrPrdCfsClient, ManufacturerName, RangeModelWithYears, callback) {
    var carTrimsQuery = solrPrdCfsClient.createQuery()
    .q('*:*')
    .start(0)
    .rows(10)
    .matchFilter('ManufacturerName','Ford')
    .matchFilter('RangeModelWithYears','"Fusion (02-12)"')
    .facet({
        on:true,
        field:'TrimName',
        mincount:'1',
    });
    solrPrdCfsClient.search(carTrimsQuery,function(err,obj) {
        if(err) {
            callback(err,null);
        }
        else {
            callback(null, obj.facet_counts.facet_fields);
        }
    });
};
```